# Python: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"'

Tags: python, csv

I'm creating code to get the average score in a CSV file.

CSV file looks like this:

```
5 Ser15

4 Ser15

3 Ser15
```

1st column are the scores, the second are the usernames.

This is my code so far:

```
   def av():
    with open("SciMedreport.csv","r") as f:
        average = 0
        Sum = 0
        row_count = 0
        for row in f:
            column = row.split(',')
            i=(int(column[0]))
            Sum += i
            row_count += 1
        average = Sum / row_count
        return 'The average is:', average
  av()
```

But this error appears...

```
  i=int(column[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '"'
```

When I print the whole row to check, this appears:

```
def av():
with open("SciMedreport.csv","r") as f:
    average = 0
    Sum = 0
    row_count = 0
    for row in f:
        print(row)
av()
```

This is the result:

```
5,Ser15
""

5,Ser15

""

4,Ser15
```

Anyone know of a way to fix this, or an alternative way to work out the average??

Comment: That code won't work with the data you posted. Your code splits lines on commas but there are no commas in your data. Please post the actual code you are running and the actual data you are using.

Comment: The data is the csv above, should I remove the comma part?

Comment: i agree with @Imcoins . you're just trying to get the result, understand what each line is doing. like here, in your revised version, you should check that what have been returned by split, if you do so , you'll know that it needs and index, as the separeated parts are both the score and the username

Comment: How would I be able to check? I'm rather new to python, I still find it confusing...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

when you try to split your row by ',' as there is none, whole string will be returned and trying to convert it into int() gives you the error, try splitting using ' '

Comment: for column in row.split(''):
ValueError: empty separator

Comment: put the space seperator in there like split(' '), see the space in between? it should be there

Comment: I will update my code above, but a new error shows, I will post it.

Comment: Try to read the errors you are getting, and think about what you want to do. If you want an immediate answer and don't understand what behind it, you won't know how to reproduce it.

Comment: I understand, I'm new to python so when I search what the error means it gives answers I find complicated and difficult to understand...

Comment: that's ok, you're doing great, what i meant was you can do a little debugging programming, like here, after split, try checking it like (Type(row.split(' '))) and print(row.split(' ')) to see what you've got and what you need to do. well done

Comment: I see, I'll try now! Thanks

Comment: 5,Ser15
['""\n']
['5,Ser15\n']
['""\n']
['4,Ser15\n']

Comment: This appears, is the error the fact that it prints newline?

Comment: you see, that's a step forward, now your data seems to have the comma (',') you mentioned before, but in your input sample in the question it didn't , it can be the newline, but here the score and user name are not separated, try playing around with split and their indexes until it works

Comment: How would I separate them? Would I need to use the split function again?

Comment: no, i guess following @user3903448's routine will help you more, have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

I am able to see a couple of errors in the code.

```
for row in f:
(1)    for column in row.split(','):
(2)            i=(int(column))
            Sum += i
        row_count += 1
(3)    average = Sum / len(column)
```

(1) When you split the row, what you get back is basically an array/list. In your case, it would be `['5', 'Ser15]`. And instead of a for loop, you might want to change the code as follows:

```
for row in f:
    columns_list = row.split(',')
    i=(int(columns_list[0]))
    Sum += i
    row_count += 1
average = Sum / row_count
```

(2) Now you can't convert a list to an integer. What you might be interested in is `i = int(column[0])` i.e. first number in the list i.e. first column of your CSV file.

(3) You want to find the average of all rows, right? Souldn't it be `average = Sum / row_count`?

```
def av():
    with open("SciMedreport.csv","r") as f:
        average = 0
        Sum = 0
        row_count = 0
        divisor = 0
        for row in f:
            row_count += 1
            if row_count%2 == 0: # if it doesn't work, try changing to 1
                # print(row.split(','))
                divisor += 1
                # write rest of the code here, Sum += i etc.
                columns_list = row.split(',')
                i = int(columns_list[0])
                Sum += i
        average = Sum / divisor
```

Comment: Can you try the suggested modification (See point (1))? Whats the error?

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '""\n'
>>>

Comment: I sense some problem with the input format. Try printing the row variable and update it. It should be easy to debug then. for row in f: print row and once you set columns_list, also print columns_list and you will know what all is happening.

Comment: This is what is printed when I just print the row.                              
5,Ser15
""

5,Ser15

""

4,Ser15

Comment: But under each other.

Comment: Can you post exactly as you see it? Copy paste it in the question description. Also, print the columns_list as suggested. There is a problem in input format only. Once you print it, it would be clear.

Comment: I know you are getting two opinions at the same time. I would suggest you to keep .split(',') as is. Secondly, I observe that you are getting '""\n' in alternate rows. So easiest solution would be to check whether that thing comes on even count or odd count and based on that just skip the processing. This will definitely work

Comment: What do you mean even and odd?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, I feel as if I am getting more confused by the minute...

Comment: Please check the updated answer, it should be clear now.

Comment: This is printed                                                                                          
['""\n']
['""\n']

Comment: Since in my previous code Sum+= i, but in you code there is no variable to define i, should I replace i with 1?

Comment: perfect. If "This is printed ['""\n'] ['""\n']" this is the case, change that row_count%2 == 1 to row_count%2 == 0.

Comment: "Since in my previous code Sum+= i ....." those things still need to be there. Inside the if that I added. columns_list = row.split(',') --- i = int(columns_list[0]) --- Sum += i --- all these you need to add... Please read the comments that I have put.

Comment: I have updated the answer again. I expect it to work immediately if you just copy paste it.

Comment: wait, I just added print! I'm a bit slow... Thank you so much, you saved my project!

Comment: Kindly accept the answer if that has helped. I would like to know what change you made to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

```
def av():
    with open("SciMedreport.csv","r") as f:
        average = 0
        Sum = 0
        row_count = 0
        divisor = 0
        for row in f:
            row_count += 1
            if row_count%2 == 0: # if it doesn't work, try changing to 1
                # print(row.split(','))
                divisor += 1
                # write rest of the code here, Sum += i etc.
                columns_list = row.split(',')
                i = int(columns_list[0])
                Sum += i
        average = Sum / divisor
```

Thank you to user3903448!